# Razor TextAreaFor Disabled Attribute Is Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This code is not working:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Question.StopReason, new { @style = "height:60px;width:300px", @disabled = Model.Question.IsStop ? "disabled" : "false" })
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable your `TextArea` based on a condition, you can use `JQuery` to achieve that.

First assign a `id` to your element:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Question.StopReason, new { @style = "height:60px;width:300px", @id="mytextarea" })
```

Then you can use the following code snippet to achieve your scenarion:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var mycondition=@Json.Encode(Model.Question.StopReason);
      if(mycondition == true){
        $('#mytextarea').prop("disabled", true);
       }
       else{
         $('#mytextarea').prop("disabled", false);
       }
    }); 
</script>
```